# Seeking help to understand the arguments of Elliptic Curve Expression in SageMath

Tags: elliptic-curves

Good Day. I'm sorry for my sage code, without formulas, but I looking your help friend.

```
p = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F
F = FiniteField(p)
E = EllipticCurve(F,[0,7])
print(E[0])
```

**what mean E[0] ????**

It very hard to calculate E[0], so, I'm looking for your help friends.

Comment: Could you ask at https://ask.sagemath.org/ ?

Comment: This is cryptography quescion kalalalaka. Thank you for your answer. Can you help ?

Comment: As you see this has nothing to do with cryptography.se. It is all about how the SageMath is working.

Comment: Are you after the order $n$ of the group for [secp256k1](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1)? Yes [it's an involved computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_points_on_elliptic_curves#Schoof%E2%80%93Elkies%E2%80%93Atkin_algorithm), but that's not a secret. PS: It tried to migrate the question to SO, but the system didn't agree, and closed it.

Comment: And don't cross-post; [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4007571/338051)

Answer (score 2):

`E[n]` returns the $n$-th point in its list of $F$-rational points.

Source: `__getitem__` in

https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/develop/src/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_finite_field.py

Comment: Ok. And why E[0] eating 256 GB computer memory and noting found ? What answer of E[0] ???

Comment: Because your curve is too large and it tries to generate the list of $F$-rational points before returning you the first element.

Comment: Okey. And there is a dictionary about this rational point ?

Comment: $F$-rational points are just points with coordinates in $F$.

Comment: Myath, this is not simple coordinates - this like: sage: E = EllipticCurve('11a'); E
            Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + y = x^3 - x^2 - 10*x - 20 over Rational Field
            sage: P = E(0); P
            (0 : 1 : 0)

Comment: `E[0]` is not implemented for the field $\mathbb{Q}$. Note the difference between `E[0]` (with brackets) and `E(0)` (with parentheses), which is the neutral point.

Comment: It looks like the issue you have is due to sage wanting to compute the whole list at once, and then return it. Python has anticipated issues like this, and has something called *iterators* to fix it, which generate elements online (this is the `__iter__` method in the linked documentation). The `iter` implementation in this case looks simplistic though, and I would assume that it still computes the entire list of rational points beforehand, so I doubt this will fix your problem (but in general iterators are good to keep in mind to solve this issue in Python).

Comment: Mark, big thank you for your answer. I solve I think my task, I put a and b coefficients and code work fine.And E[0] i replace to order of a G. I banned now from posting new questions, Then I can post new question I can continue talk. Big thank you !